# anbox cloud installation

Tags: anbox

I am trying to install anbox cloud appliance on a dedicated machine.
But anbox-cloud-appliance is failing .

Please help me in resolving this issue. (Attached all required info below)

```
omadmin@ubuntu-server-pro:~$ sudo pro status
[sudo] password for omadmin: 
SERVICE          ENTITLED  STATUS    DESCRIPTION
esm-apps         yes       enabled   Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications
esm-infra        yes       enabled   Expanded Security Maintenance for Infrastructure
livepatch        yes       enabled   Canonical Livepatch service
realtime-kernel* yes       disabled  Ubuntu kernel with PREEMPT_RT patches integrated
usg              yes       disabled  Security compliance and audit tools

 * Service has variants

For a list of all Ubuntu Pro services and variants, run 'pro status --all'
Enable services with: pro enable <service>

     Account: srinidhikrs@yahoo.com
Subscription: Ubuntu Pro - free personal subscription


omadmin@ubuntu-server-pro:~$ juju status -m appliance:admin/anbox-cloud
Model        Controller  Cloud/Region       Version  SLA          Timestamp
anbox-cloud  appliance   appliance/default  2.9.33   unsupported  14:11:34Z

App                    Version  Status       Scale  Charm                  Channel  Rev  Exposed  Message
ams                             error            1  ams                               0  no       hook failed: "install"
anbox-cloud-dashboard           error            1  anbox-cloud-dashboard             0  no       hook failed: "install"
anbox-stream-agent              maintenance      1  anbox-stream-agent                0  no       installing charm software
anbox-stream-gateway            error            1  anbox-stream-gateway              0  no       hook failed: "install"
coturn                 4.5.2    active           1  coturn                            0  yes      
etcd                   3.4.22   active           1  etcd                              0  no       Healthy with 1 known peer
etcd-ca                3.0.1    active           1  easyrsa                           0  no       Certificate Authority connected.
grafana                         active           1  grafana                           0  no       Ready
internal-ca            3.0.1    active           1  easyrsa                           0  no       Certificate Authority connected.
lxd-integrator                  active           1  lxd-integrator                    0  no       
nats                            active           1  nats                              0  no       
prometheus                      active           1  prometheus2                       0  no       Ready

Unit                      Workload     Agent      Machine  Public address  Ports                              Message
ams/0*                    error        idle       1        240.0.204.180                                      hook failed: "install"
anbox-cloud-dashboard/0*  error        idle       1        240.0.204.180                                      hook failed: "install"
anbox-stream-agent/0*     maintenance  executing  1        240.0.204.180                                      (install) installing charm software
anbox-stream-gateway/0*   error        idle       1        240.0.204.180                                      hook failed: "install"
coturn/0*                 active       idle       1        240.0.204.180   5349/tcp,5349/udp,60000-60100/udp  
etcd-ca/0*                active       idle       0        240.0.157.184                                      Certificate Authority connected.
etcd/0*                   active       idle       1        240.0.204.180   2379/tcp                           Healthy with 1 known peer
grafana/0*                active       idle       2        240.0.222.116   3000/tcp                           Ready
internal-ca/0*            active       idle       0        240.0.157.184                                      Certificate Authority connected.
lxd-integrator/0*         active       idle       0        240.0.157.184                                      
nats/0*                   active       idle       1        240.0.204.180   4222/tcp                           
prometheus/0*             active       idle       2        240.0.222.116   9090/tcp,12321/tcp                 Ready

Machine  State    Address        Inst id        Series  AZ  Message
0        started  240.0.157.184  juju-bb7eef-0  jammy       Running
1        started  240.0.204.180  juju-bb7eef-1  jammy       Running
2        started  240.0.222.116  juju-bb7eef-2  focal       Running
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a fresh install/Initialization?

We had networking issues and forcing it to use the network-bridge works

Your issue may be different, I cannot tell from the note.

```
sudo anbox-cloud-appliance destroy
sudo anbox-cloud-appliance init --force-network-bridge
```

Comment: juju status -m appliance:admin/anbox-cloud shows that hook failed for ams , anbox-cloud-dashboard and anbox-stream-gateway

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you ran into an issue which has been fixed with the Ubuntu Pro service earlier today. Can you run the following:

```
$ sudo anbox-cloud-appliance destroy
$ sudo pro detach
$ sudo pro attach <your token>
$ sudo anbox-cloud-appliance init
```

This should solve the issue and you should be able to deploy without issues.

Comment: I am using ubuntu free personal subscription. (This machine is now attached to 'Ubuntu Pro - free personal subscription')

Comment: Thanks . It worked.

Comment: Glad to hear that!